# Call API before dispatching action - Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am a bit conflicted about this and seem to find no answer.
I have a slice with some actions. What I want to do is to fire a request without awaiting it's result (it's a firebase call that should be handled optimistically).

How should I then structure my code around this case? Using `createAsyncThunk` shouldn't be considered because I am not awaiting anything and dont need to update any local `requestStatus` variables.

This is what I have right now:

```
// Component.js (where I do the dispatch)

useEffect(() => dispatch(updateCheckIn(payload)), [])
```

```
// CheckInActions.js

import { updateCheckInInDb } from "../../api/checkin"
import { updateCheckInAction } from "../reducers"

export const updateCheckIn = (update) => {
  updateCheckInInDb(update) // make API call
  return updateCheckInAction(update) // return actual reducer action
}
```

```
// CheckInReducer.js

const checkInSlice = createSlice({
  name: "checkIn",
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {
    updateCheckInAction(state, action) {
      return updateStateViaUpdateApi(state.data, action)
    },
  },
})

export const { updateCheckInAction } = checkInSlice.actions
export default checkInSlice
```

This works but I feel it is a bit awkward (specially the naming). I would need to call one a `updateCheckInAction` and the other `updateCheckIn`. I am a bit new to redux toolkit. Isn't there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most idiomatic answer here would be hand-write a thunk that kicks off the async request and then dispatches the plain action:

```js
export const updateCheckIn = (update) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    // make API call
    updateCheckInInDb(update) 
    // dispatch actual action to update state
    dispatch(updateCheckInAction(update)) 
  }
}

// used as
dispatch(updateCheckIn(123))
```

See https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks for details on what thunks are overall and how to write them.

Comment: Hi Erik! Just saw your video with Jason - awesome stuff! This solution is what I also had in mind but was maybe thinking that I was missing something from the redux toolkit API. Thanks!

Comment: Sure :) Yeah, the idea of hand-writing a thunk is still 100% valid, and it's simple enough that RTK doesn't include a specific API for it. My current day job app ( https://replay.io ) has many hand-written thunks, because we need to write logic that has access to `dispatch` + `getState`, sometimes even doing async work, but that code isn't the typical "make a request and dispatch loading status actions" behavior.  So, it's just basic thunks.